Model training loss always converge to 1.35
I'm trying to create a multi-class classification model using RNNs. The input data has a sequence length of 90 and consists of 5 features, normalized to the [0,1] range.
Here's the network architecture I've attempted, which is the smallest capacity model with decreasing training loss:
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(sequence_length, feature_length))
x1 = tf.keras.layers.GRU(512)(inputs)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(x1)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")(x2)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

The largest model I tried has 3 GRU layers, each with 1024 units.
What puzzles me is that regardless of the model capacity, all models converge to around 1.35 for training loss. I don't understand why the models consistently converge to a similar value regardless of their capacity.
Does anyone know why this issue occurs and how to resolve it?

$1.35 \approx \log(4)$ so the model is doing just slightly better than randomly guessing. You could make progress by debugging the model training process https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn/352037#352037 Or perhaps the features are not informative

Thank you for your comment. It is very helpful to me!
